# Nuget, compare installed vs latest version

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Can I get a list like this from the Nuget console:

```
Id          Installed Version           Latest Version  
----        -----------------           ----------------  
NHibernate  3.3.0.4000                  3.3.3.4001
```

And even better, for all the projects in the solution?

Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can paste this all as one line in the Package Manager Console:

`$updates = @{}; Get-Package -Updates | foreach { $updates.Add($_.Id, $_.Version) }; Get-Package | foreach { New-Object Object | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Id -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Installed Version' $_.Version -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Latest Version' $updates.Get_Item($_.Id) -PassThru }`

This will give you results like:

```
Name                                       Installed Version  Latest Version
----                                       -----------------  --------------
Antlr                                      3.4.1.9004         3.5.0.2       
Autofac                                    3.2.0              3.3.0         
Autofac.Mvc5                               3.2.0                            
bootstrap                                  3.0.0              3.1.0         
EntityFramework                            6.0.0              6.0.2         
jQuery                                     1.10.2             2.1.0         
jQuery.Validation                          1.11.1                           
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core             1.0.0                            
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework  1.0.0                            
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin             1.0.0                            
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc                       5.1.0              5.1.1         
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor                     3.1.0              3.1.1         
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization          1.1.1              1.1.2         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi                    5.0.0              5.1.1         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client             5.0.0              5.1.1         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core               5.0.0              5.1.1         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost            5.0.0              5.1.1         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages                  3.1.0              3.1.1         
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation    3.0.0              3.1.1         
Microsoft.Owin                             2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb              2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Owin.Security                    2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies            2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook           2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google             2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount   2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth              2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter            2.0.0              2.1.0         
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure               1.0.0.0                          
Modernizr                                  2.6.2              2.7.1         
Newtonsoft.Json                            5.0.6              6.0.1         
Owin                                       1.0                              
RavenDB.Client                             2.5.2750                         
Respond                                    1.2.0              1.3.0         
WebGrease                                  1.5.2              1.6.0
```

Comment: Nice work...........Sometimes I like nuget, sometimes I long for Apache Ivy (standalone).

Answer (score 2):

I modified the script slightly to save the results to a text file in the solution folder called [solution filename].nuget.txt. Here's the script:

```
$updates = @{}; Get-Package -Updates | foreach { $updates.Add($_.Id, $_.Version) }; $toReview = Get-Package | foreach { New-Object Object | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Id -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Installed Version' $_.Version -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Latest Version' $updates.Get_Item($_.Id) -PassThru } | sort -Property 'Name' -Unique | Out-File "$($dte.Solution.FileName).nuget.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

got exception 'Item has already been added. Key in dictionary'. replaced *$updates.Add($*.Id, $*.Version)* by [Array]$updates[$*.Id] += $*.Version*

```
$updates = @{}; Get-Package -Updates | foreach { [Array]$updates[$_.Id] += $_.Version }; Get-Package | foreach { New-Object Object | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Id -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Installed Version' $_.Version -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Latest Version' $updates.Get_Item($_.Id) -PassThru }

$updates = @{}; Get-Package -Updates | foreach {[Array]$updates[$_.Id] += $_.Version }; $toReview = Get-Package | foreach { New-Object Object | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Id -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Installed Version' $_.Version -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Latest Version' $updates.Get_Item($_.Id) -PassThru } | sort -Property 'Name' -Unique | Out-File "$($dte.Solution.FileName).nuget.txt"
```