# How can I automatically detect whether my NuGet packages are up to date?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, build-process, nuget-package

I'd like to get loud warnings somewhere if my project is using a dependency that's now out of date (potentially I might hook this into our build, so builds using certain outdated dependencies are automatically failed and can't be deployed).

If possible I'd like to do this for dependencies on our other internal projects only, to start with, so that if I publish a new version of a shared internal library, all other projects using that library are loudly notified/required to update to the new one, but so we don't have to immediately upgrade to the newest version of entity framework every time it's upgraded.

Is there a way to easily check whether all or a subset of my NuGet dependencies are up to date from the package manager console, or with an MSBuild task?

Comment: What exactly is driving this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm working within multiple teams, and we're using various common components. It's very important that we don't deploy two projects with different versions of some of these common components, and I want our build pipeline to provide as much security against that as possible, by loudly notifying people when there are updates they've missed.

Comment: Why is it necessary to have the same version of components at build time? It sounds like you might be better off splitting off the shared component as a separate service.

Comment: Not practical I'm afraid: the performance hit for an extra network round-trip is unworkable for this, even just within one data center, and it adds quite a bit of complexity to the system compared to just sharing dlls. It has to be done in-process.

We are potentially looking at hot-swapping DLLs later, to manage the dependency independently in the deployment environment, but not in the short-term.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of all your installed packages and the latest version on NuGet.

I created a PowerShell script to do this. You can find it here:

[Nuget, compare installed vs latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849790/nuget-compare-installed-vs-latest-version/)

Answer (score 2):

If desired it's possible to manually query the public API for NuGet to retrieve package information.  They have a newer JSON api which i was able to use in a NodeJS app, and they have an older XML api.

#### JSON api

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

**All versions of a package**:
https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration0/newtonsoft.json/index.json

**Specific package at version**:
https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration0/newtonsoft.json/4.0.1.json

*(keep in mind that the package ID in the URL must be all lowercased!)*

---

#### XML api

https://nuget.org/api/v2/

**All Packages** (paged -first 100): https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages

Next page of 100: 
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages?$skip=100

**Specific package at version**: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='NewtonSoft.Json',Version='4.0.1')

With the XML version I don't know of a way to list all versions of a package, but when you visit the versioned package there is a boolean value for `<d:IsLatestVersion>` and `<d:IsAbsoluteLatestVersion>` (I'm not sure what the difference is though... perhaps one exclude pre-release versions?)

Comment: I want to clarify as this answer helped me reach a solution - LInks provided for the the JSON API are slightly different (perhaps changed since time of answer). The /registration0/ property should be /registration3/. Not sure when the change occurred (and registration0 does not appear in the v3 API anymore). The difference it made for me was that I used the API to see what's the latest version of a package. For example, Newtonsoft.Json ends at version 10.0.2 in /registration0/ as opposed to (accurate at time of writing) 12.0.1-beta2 in /registration3/. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to suscribe to the RSS feed found in the package webpage at nuget.org, at the bottom of the page.